# Error trying to FTP files to Azure

Tags: azure, ftp

I am trying to FTP some file to my Azure web site using FileZilla. However it doesn't seem to be connecting. It keeps getting blocked at the "**Initializing TLS...**" message.

Here's a screenshot of the log from FileZilla.

[image]

Here are my FileZilla settings.

[image]

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Did you try another FTP client? (e.g. [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/)?)

Comment: the username is websitename\username . if you have not tried it already...

Comment: @Aravind You are right. But the problem happens before authentication.

Answer (score -1):

Few details to make it work.

First I don't think you need Encryption : make it a simple (unsecured) connexion. Lame my FileZilla is in french for exact terms.

Second, you're user shall more looks like "blah-blah\$blah-blah" as shown in your connection profile in Azure Portal.

Last, and really least, port 21 is default port and could be erase.

Hope you'll figure this out !

Comment: *"I don't think you need Encryption"* - That's a joke, right? - And the other suggestions are irrelevant to the problem.